How to create the Lauterbach new instance window automatically?
I have a Lauterbach script called "test.cmm" that perform another instance for multi-core debugging. I want to create a batch script to automate this action. If I am currently connected to Lauterbach and running on, for example, core 1, can I create a new instance of that Lauterbach connection by automatically by running this batch script? I would like to run the "test.cmm" script without manually clicking "Run Script" in the current window. I have attached an image for reference. Any sample script would helpful to understand the concept.


Note the relatively low number of followers for each the tags you have used. BUT in any case, your question doesn't meet a basic requirement for stackOverflow Qs. See [mcve] , update your Q and add a tag for the progamming language and/or OS you are using. Also look to see if a new "forum" has appeared here on StackExchange.com related to ARM development. (Let me know if you find one (-; ).  Good luck.

I'm not quite sure what you're asking for....
Do you want test.cmm to run automatically after the GUI has been started?
Or do you need the command to open a new GUI (for AMP multicore debugging) to add that command to test.cmm?
Or do you want to open a new GUI (for AMP multicore debugging) that will automatically run test.cmm?

@Holger I want to create a batch script that will open a new GUI (for AMP multicore debugging) that will automatically run test.cmm

@user2986042 Do you want a BATCH script to open the second GUI or do you want a CMM script to open the second GUI? Because if you want a batch script just do it the same way as the first GUI, add -s <script> for the startup script. If you want a CMM script then look into the command TargetSystem.NewInstance which allows you to that easily.

Since you are running the Arm version of PowerView, you should have quite a few multicore demos and some scripts that you could modify for your own use case already in your installed files.
One such example would be ~~~~/demo/arm/hardware/imx8/imx8m/imx8mq-evk/imx8mq-amp/ which contains a Windows batch file and a Bash script for starting PowerView from the console in AMP mode. In this same folder, there is a configuration file (config_amp.t32) and a startup script (t32_amp.cmm) plus a demonstration of how the InterCom command is used to control another instance after TargetSystem.NewInstance is used to open a different PowerView window.
If you have a debugger with dual whisker, there is another demo available (~~~~demo/arm/combiprobe/dual_whisker/start_amp.bat) showing this functionality although much of the concepts are similar to the aforementioned demo.
As for running a cmm script from PowerView? The command DO from within PowerView is one of many ways. You can create menu items with keyboard shortcuts to execute test.cmm—part of that i.MX8 AMP demo, also detailed in ~~~~/pdf/training_menu.pdf. To run arbitrary commands/scripts from an automation script, you can use the t32rem executable on an API-enabled (via its configuration script) PowerView instance to send these commands.
